# Arpabet phonemes to Text-to-speech engine

Tags: macos, audio, tts

I'm using the [Carnegie Mellon Pronouncing Dictionary](ftp://ftp.cs.cmu.edu/project/fgdata/dict/README) for a project and it stores words as a pair consisting of the word and then the phonemes in [Arpabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpabet) style...

> hello -HH AH0 L OW1

I'd like to be able to feed the phones back into a Text-To-Speech engine, but here I get a bit lost - my 'say' command on OSX doesn't accept the same set of phonemes (and nethier does espeak) - is there a (free) system for OSX that let's me input phonemes in  [Arpabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpabet) style and get audio out?  (Or, for that matter, something that converts between different sets of phonemes?)

Answer (score 1):

For eSpeak, you need a [*Arpabet to IPA*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Arpabet+to+ipa) table. With that you can convert the CMU-DICT to IPA and then use it with eSpeak. A different mapping might be needed for `say` as phone set system it uses might be different.